# Deleted k8s cluster in aws dashboard and now terraform is erroring out

Tags: amazon-web-services, kubernetes, terraform, terraform-provider-aws, amazon-eks

I created a k8s eks cluster and all of it's resources within terraform but ran into some issues and deleted the cluster through the aws UI. Now when I try to run terraform I'm getting this error `Error: Get "http://localhost/api/v1/persistentvolumes/efs-jupyter-shared-v2": dial tcp 127.0.0.1:80: connect: connection refused` for each of the resources. I tried commenting out all of the resources within terraform and running, and still got the same error. Any ideas how to proceed?

Comment: One way is to remove those Kubernetes/helm resources from the state file. remove every block that depended on Kubernetes. or may recreate with terraform and then destroy if you don't want to mess with state file

Comment: I can't even recreate. It's trying to refresh state and failing because the cluster doesn't exist.

Comment: then remove those resources manually from the state file and set the count to 0 for the interrupted resources

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to clean the terraform state:

First step is listing all the resources in the state:

```bash
terraform state list
```

Then you can delete the resources you deleted in AWS dashboard:

```bash
terraform state rm <resource_name>
```

Finally you can run your terraform code to recreate the resources.